# Play Framework 2.1 - Syntax error using java.util.properties in Play Controller

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am having a strange sort of conflict when attempting to use the java.util.Properties class in a Play Controller, consider the following:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Simple extends Controller {

   Properties prop = new Properties();

   prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");

}
```

In Eclipse the setProperty method returns:

Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

I think there is some conflict with this code being within a Controller, the same two lines work in a simple Java class in a bespoke package.

Any help would be much appreciated, I am new Play with some Java experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these two lines inside a method block:

```
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Simple extends Controller {
    public static void pickABetterMethodName() { // Method 
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
    }
}
```

This will solve the syntax problem. The reason is that you can't have code that is not method or field declaration in the class declaration itself. Behavior is implemented in methods. Here's the Java Tutorial about [class declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) and here the about [method declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

I think what you're trying to do is execute code during the controller initialization. If I remember correctly, in Play 1.x this was possible with a `@OnApplicationStart` decorator (on a method). I'm not sure this is still the case with Play 2.x.

**Edit**: With Play 2.x you do this with the [Application global settings](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal).

Comment: You also could tell him/her why. ;-)

Comment: You're right @alexvetter. I tried to improve the answer a bit. :-)

Comment: Thanks dschulz, I really appreciate your answer and also alexvetter for prompting the rationale, makes perfect sense, oversight on my part.  I think with Play 2.1 you can define a Global class to bootstrap code.

Comment: dschulz - Beat me to it regarding the Global class, thanks very much again, I have accepted your answer :-)